# Floating image to the left changes container div's height

Tags: css

When I try to run the following:

```
​<div id="container">
     //This is a 200x200 image        
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/CCC/000" />
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

with CSS:

```
​#container {
    background:#000;
}
```

​I get a DIV with a black background container like I want.

However, when I add the following to the CSS:

```
#container img {
   float:left;
}
```

It seems like the container does not detect the image inside it and its height is set to minimum (can be seen here:  http://jsfiddle.net/wc4GJ/ ).

How come floating the image to the left mess up the container DIV's height?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto;` to `#container`

(Explanations below)

Comment: Why should adding an image (with a fixed width and height) be considered as an overflow for the DIV?

Comment: Because floating takes the element out from the flow, which means that the parent element no longer has any content in it that determines its height. Adding overflow: hidden/auto; to the parent ensures that it wraps its contents properly.

Comment: Genius. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a clearing div after the img:

```
​<div id="container">
     //This is a 200x200 image        
     <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/CCC/000" />
     <div class="clearing"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And in CSS:

```
.clearing { clear: both; }
```

Comment: What is the reason for this? Shouldn't the container DIV recognize an image inside of it, even though it is floated to the left?

Comment: Worked well for me embedding youtube videos in a list of Polymer containers where overflow:auto didn't quite do the job (the video expanded and subsequent containers in the list were bumped down, but the embedding container didn't expand)