# float makes div not surround children

Tags: html, css

The following HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
        <div style="float: left;">
            Expected NPV</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

...renders a parent DIV with a blue border and a child DIV inside.  However, the float:left; directive makes the parent not surround the child with a border (which is what I desire).

Is there a way to make this happen w/out removing the float:left?

I boiled the HTML down to a very simple example to illustrate the basic problem.  I realize float:left; is nonsensical in this example, but it is required from the original HTML.  I can post that if it would be more helpful.

Comment: Trouble is without context we can't tell if float is appropriate - display: inline might be better suited for all we know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give the parent an `overflow` to take the child's height into account, like this:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="float: left;">
        Expected NPV</div>
</div>
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2naMH/).  For a full explanation, [check out the excellent write-up on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).  Note that `overflow: hidden` also works here, [you can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2naMH/1/).

Answer (score 3):

Use `overflow:auto;` eg. on the container.

Similar problem : [Floating image to the left changes container div's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921761/floating-image-to-the-left-changes-container-divs-height/3921781#3921781)